# How to remove ending zeros in binary bit sequence in R?

Tags: r, binary, truncate

I need to remove ending zeros from binary bit sequences.
The length of the bit sequence is fixed, say 52. i.e.,

```
0101111.....01100000 (52-bit), 
10111010..1010110011 (52-bit),
10111010..1010110100 (52-bit).
```

From converting decimal number to normalized double precision, significand is 52 bit, and hence zeros are populated to the right hand side even if significand is less than 52 bit at first step. I am reversing the process: i.e., I am trying to convert a normalized double precision in memory to decimal number, hence, I have to remove zeros (at the end) that are used to populate 52 bits for significand.

It is not guaranteed that the sequence in hand necessarily have 0s in the end (like the 2nd example above). If there is, all ending zeros must be truncated:

```
f(0101111.....01100000) # 0101111.....011; leading 0 must be kept
f(10111010..1010110011) # 10111010..1010110011; no truncation
f(10111010..1010110100) # 10111010..10101101
```

Unfortunately, the number of truncated 0s at the end differs. (5 in the 1st example; 2 in the 3rd example).

It is OK for me if input and output class are `string`:

```
f("0101111.....01100000") # "0101111.....011"; leading 0 must be kept
f("10111010..1010110011") # "10111010..1010110011"; no truncation
f("10111010..1010110100") # "10111010..10101101"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For ... some ... reason ??

Comment: From converting decimal number to normalized double precision, significand is 52 bit, and hence zeros are populated to the right hand side even if significand is less than 52 bit at first step. I am reversing the process: i.e., I am trying to convert a normalized double precision in memory to decimal number, hence, I have to remove zeros (at the end) that are used to populate 52 bits for significand.

Comment: `f <- function(x) sub('0+$', '', x)`. Then, `f("0101111.....01100000")`.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the zeroes on the **left** side of that binary number?

Comment: OK.  Well, the zeroes on the left side of a binary number are of no consequence.  To remove the zeroes on the right side of the number is a right-shift.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, nope, right. Observe: 86.125 decimal is converted to 0100000001010101100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. In this normalized double precison, 0101100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 is normalized significand whom ending zeros are put just for the sake of obtaining IEEE754 52 bit significand.

Comment: Is the number of extra zeroes always the same?

Comment: Not same. It changes according to the given decimal number.

Comment: How do you know how many zeroes to remove?

Comment: I do not know. That is the problem itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple regular expression.

```
f <- function(x) sub('0+$', '', x)
```

Explanation:

1. `0` - matches the character `0`.
2. `0+` - the character zero repeated at least one time, meaning, one or more times.
3. `$` matches the end of the string.
4. `0+$` the character `0` repeated one or more times and nothing else until the end of the string.
5. Replace the sub-string matched by the pattern with the empty string, `''`.

Now test the function.

```
f("010111101100000")
#[1] "0101111011"
f("0100000001010101100010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000") 
#[1] "010000000101010110001"
f("010000000101010110001000000") 
#[1] "010000000101010110001"
f("00010000000101010110001000000")
#[1] "00010000000101010110001"
```